# Crystal report not support null Datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, crystal-reports, dbnull

I am using crystal report with ado.Net, when datetime is coming null from database then  showing error. if we use Nullable (using ?) property then crystal report can't support.

**Like:-**

```
 _report = (
       from user in users  
               select new userModel()
               {
                   UserId = user.Field<string>("userid"),
                   CheckInTime = <user.Field<DateTime>("intime"),
                   CheckOutTime = user.Field<DateTime>("outime"),
                   TotalWorks = user.Field<Int32>("TotalWork")
               })
               .ToList();
```

**throwing error here......**

and when we use Nullabe..:-

```
    public DateTime? CheckInTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CheckOutTime { get; set; }

               CheckInTime = <user.Field<DateTime?>("intime"),
               CheckOutTime = user.Field<DateTime?>("outime"),
```

then Crystal report not supporting.

having any best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to convert that date variable to string (and make it blank if null), before passing it to crystal report, and use it as a string in crystal report.

Comment: but Here " CheckInTime = <user.Field<DateTime>("intime")," throwing error

Comment: @JasRajBishnoi:Take that field as a string only... first change your query to convert date to string and then put that string in string variable instead of date :)