# crystal report wants db login and nullable problems

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

hi guys i wonder if someone can answer my question .

i use this following code for printing some data from sqlserver database and my database dosent have any permission or logins just windows authentications i use following code but

```
i have this error(DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>)
```

and when in print form i use the same code i have database login error that does not solve anyway

```
 private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   print_form fm = new print_form();
   mydbDataContext db = new mydbDataContext();
   CrystalReport1 cm = new CrystalReport1();
   cm.SetDataSource(dataGridView3.DataSource);
   fm.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cm;
   fm.Show();
   }
```

please help me and i use visual studio 2012 and newest crystal report package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal report will not support Nullable variable or property , if you have create Nullable variable or property then Crystal report will throw error.
so you have to use non Nullable propety.

please refer below link.

[Crystal report not support null Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882891/crystal-report-not-support-null-datetime)